# Why not yield/iterable in posts interface?

Tags: php, posts, get-posts

I was reading an article on the [advantage of *yield* statements and iterables](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) - a handy and useful thing where *"the list is so large that merely creating it would consume all of the system's memory"*

PHP also has [yield statments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) (generators).

This would have practical implications in Wordpress - sometimes I have had to fix a site that exceeded memory limits from Wordpress' grabbing comments when thousands of spammy comments are pending in the database.

I have to wonder why Wordpress still creates a whole array of data in memory for get_posts and similar - is this something that has just never been considered, or something they absolutely have to have in array in memory for legacy code, and is impractical to rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the [recommendations](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) have been updated to:

> To run WordPress we recommend your host supports:
>
> - PHP version 5.6 or greater
> - MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater

the [minimum requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress) are not there yet:

> WordPress server requirements for Version 3.2+:
>
> - PHP version 5.2.4 or greater
> - MySQL version 5.0.15 or greater or any version of MariaDB
>
> Note that older versions of MySQL and PHP may have reached End Of
>   Life, which means they are no longer updated and can expose your site
>   to security vulnerabilities. For this reason, it's best to follow the
>   recommended setup below and use the latest versions of MySQL/MariaDB
>   and PHP that your host supports.

The reason for this is [e.g.](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/):

> Why do we support older versions? We strongly recommend the latest
>   versions of PHP and MySQL, but we understand that this isn’t right for
>   everyone, and that sometimes hosts can be slow or hesitant to upgrade
>   their customers since upgrades to PHP and MySQL have historically
>   broken applications.

Hopefully the WordPress core will apply all these handy things like *generators* (PHP 5.5+) and  *namespaces* (PHP 5.3+) but it will take time.

Here's e.g. a discusssion in [#36335](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36335) regarding *autoloading* with support for PHP 5.2+.

WordPress core also [runs fine](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/10/wordpress-and-php7/) on PHP 7.

But we can of course use these PHP improvements in our own projects and many plugins are not following the minimum requirements, thankfully ;-)

Comment: Aren't generators just easy iterators? "Generators provide an easy way to implement simple iterators without the overhead or complexity of implementing a class that implements the Iterator interface." - and iterator has been around since PHP5 according to documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: yes, but the *yield* statement was introduced in PHP 5.5, Maybe you mean iterator interfaces in general? I could found e.g. suggestions in ticket [#20296](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20296) that was *closed* and [#20297](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20297) that was closed as *maybelater*. @NoBugs

Comment: ps: It will be interesting to follow this "Requests" ticket [#33055](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33055) and check out the Iterator interfaces implemented [there‌](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes/Requests)​. For example the `IteratorAggregate` [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d7e743a2864d397685b6083bf4c2e654e5ce573f/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php#L15) that was mentioned in ticket #20297 @NoBugs

Comment: Where do you find those minimum requirements?